# How to get a path to generate dataset as an input in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm new to shiny, so don't mind me if my question is simple.
I want to take a path as an input from the user and generate the data frame. I've done this so far:

```
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("data_path", "Please enter the path of your data: ")
  tableOutput("data_glimpse")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  data <- read.csv(input$data_path)
  output$data_glimpse <- renderTable({
    glimpse(data)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

But it's not working right. I don't get any pages to enter my path!

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is easier to upload the file directly. But if you want to keep this structure, you can try the following. To make it work you have to add to your path the name of the file plus .csv, e.g. /sample.csv

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("data_path", "Please enter the path of your data: "),
  tableOutput("data_glimpse")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  
  dataTable <- reactive({
    data <- read.csv(input$data_path)
  })

  output$data_glimpse <- renderTable({
  
  dplyr::glimpse(dataTable())
  
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```